# Не работает получение всех сущностей из репозитория в MongoDb

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb, rest

Изучаю MongoDb. Подключил базу к проекту на Spring Boot.

**A`application.properties`:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=spring
```

**Person модель:**

```
@Data
@Document(collation = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
}
```

**Person repo:**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

**Person controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/people/")
public class PersonController {
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public PersonController(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> people() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Запускаю код и вылетает ошибка:**

[image]

**[Код на GitHub](https://github.com/artmcoder/MongoDbLearn)**

<sub>Так же хотел спросить, где лучше всего изучать mongodb в spring boot?</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59533641/312041

Comment: Читаете текст исключения, потом ищете ошибку тут `@Document(collation = "people")`

Answer (score 0):

> Похоже, это опечатка и причина вашей проблемы.  Вы пытаетесь установить имя коллекции, но вместо коллекции вы используете свойство сопоставления: [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/)

Нужно исправить

```
@Document(collation = "people")
```

на

```
@Document(collection = "people")
```

Изучать можно [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/437410/).

Comment: Исправили ошибку?